# Unable to open salesforce classic project in Mavensmate

Tags: force.com

I am using Salesforce Classic, and Sublime Text and Mavensmate (0.0.11) IDE for force.com development. It was working fine but now suddenly, Mavensmate shows a blank screen when trying to open the existing project/create a new project (attached screenshot for ref). I tried using Visual Studio code editor and found that the format of object files are completely different. As it's a existing project, replacing the new format is a huge effort. Is there a way to resolve issues with Mavensmate?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Think you are missing your screenshot but the Mavensmate team have ceased to support the solution and have advised you should migrate to VS Code and SFDX for security reasons. See [Mavensmate: Getting error client identifier invalid while authentication to salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/270803/mavensmate-getting-error-client-identifier-invalid-while-authentication-to-sale)

Try creating a new project using the SFDX VS Code extension https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/getting-started/install

Best

Paul

Comment: Thanks Paul. I created a new project from SF classic org using VS code extension. But I found the file formats (Ex: 'object' file in classic format has all the fields & listviews in a single file. But SFDX has a different format with fields & listviews in different files). Is there any way to convert this code to classic format?